# How to Add Nested Object to an Array of Results

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, rest

I have shortened this to be easier to read but imagine if there were 1000 of these objects.
How would I get just get the "._source"?
I'm trying something like this and I know this is wrong but I'm trying to figure out the correct way to do this.

```
const myObj = response.data;

let keys = Object.keys(myObj);
keys.forEach(v => v.startsWith("_source");
```

Comment: You want just the `source` key and value, or just the value?

Comment: It is not clear what your expected output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access the object's "_source" property, i.e. `el._source`. Do what you want with the value from there.

```js
const response = [{
  "_index": "mag",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "M6RRVXIButyqFO_PBdiU",
  "_score": 12.512785,
  "_source": {
    "paper_id": "2029523142"
  }
}, {
  "_index": "mag",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "CR3VNnIButyqFO_PY3B1",
  "_score": 12.149078,
  "_source": {
    "paper_id": "2499756461"
  }
}, ];

const data = response.map(el => el._source);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: `source`, not `score` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply `for loop`

```js
var obj = [{"_index":"mag","_type":"_doc","_id":"M6RRVXIButyqFO_PBdiU","_score":12.512785,"_source":{"paper_id":"2029523142"}},{"_index":"mag","_type":"_doc","_id":"CR3VNnIButyqFO_PY3B1","_score":12.149078,"_source":{"paper_id":"2499756461"}}, ];



for(var k in obj){
  console.log( '_source=>', obj[k]._source);
}
```

Comment: @Angela try `challenge: true,` option

Comment: Where is the challenge option?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
let array = [{"_index":"mag","_type":"_doc","_id":"M6RRVXIButyqFO_PBdiU","_score":12.512785,"_source":{"paper_id":"2029523142"}},{"_index":"mag","_type":"_doc","_id":"CR3VNnIButyqFO_PY3B1","_score":12.149078,"_source":{"paper_id":"2499756461"}} ]
  
var targetValues = array.map(value => value._source);
```

of simply use loop for

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myObj.map(item=>item._source)
```

```js
myObj=[{"_index":"mag","_type":"_doc","_id":"M6RRVXIButyqFO_PBdiU","_score":12.512785,"_source":{"paper_id":"2029523142"}},{"_index":"mag","_type":"_doc","_id":"CR3VNnIButyqFO_PY3B1","_score":12.149078,"_source":{"paper_id":"2499756461"}}, ]

console.log(myObj.map(item=>item._source));
```